# Hazelcast Mancenter Time Travelling Configuration

Tags: hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast Mancenter 3.7 enabling the "Time Travelling" option.

We have been checking associated documentation:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#checking-past-status-with-time-travel

And we would like to know if there is some way to configure a monitoring timeslot once you have turned time travel option on.

Thanks a lot

Best Regards,
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct configuration(or API) available to enable/disable the monitoring during a specified time interval. Once it is enabled, it keeps logging the current state every 5 seconds to a file(*.db/*.lg).

Management center is not an open source product so we can not directly read those files or query on those files. This would be an awesome feature for those who have got license for it.

PS: I am not a JS guy, so may be there is a way to do that using Javascript/Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is any hook available to configure the Time travel for timeslot in hazelcast. If I found something I will share with you.

Thanks